# Navigation Property Is Returning Null Properties

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

Thus project works fine in .Net Framework but now I'm trying to do it in .Net Core 3 but its not working properly.

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
public class BasketLine
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BasketId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

So what happens is iI can add to the BasketLine table and calculate the total of all Products, however when I load the Cart page I get a NullReferenceException

On the Cart Page if I comment out `@Model.BasketLines[i].Product.Name` or any navigation properties, the Cart Page works

This is the addBasket method

```
public void AddToBasket(int productId, int quantity)
    {
        var basketLine = db.BasketLines.FirstOrDefault(b => b.BasketId == BasketId &&
                                                                    b.ProductId == productId);
        if (basketLine == null)
        {
            basketLine = new BasketLine
            {
                ProductId = productId,
                BasketId = BasketId,
                Quantity = quantity,
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now
            };
            db.BasketLines.Add(basketLine);
        }
        else
        {
            basketLine.Quantity += quantity;
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Am I missing something because I have no clue what I'm doing wrong here

Added Include didn't change a thing, then a strange thing happened, I changed this

```
<a asp-area="Customer"
  asp-controller="Shop"
  asp-action="Details"
  asp-route-id="@Model.BasketLines[i].ProductId">
  @Model.BasketLines[i].Product.Name
</a>
```

to this

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.BasketLines[i].Product.Name, "Details", "Products", new { id = Model.BasketLines[i].ProductId }, null)<br />
```

then the everything worked for a few tries then I got the same error all over again

```
AspNetCore.Areas_Customer_Views_Basket_Index.<ExecuteAsync>b__15_0() in Index.cshtml
+
                    @Html.ActionLink(Model.BasketLines[i].Product.Name, "Details", "Products", new { id = Model.BasketLines[i].ProductId }, null)<br />
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.GetChildContentAsync(bool useCachedResult, HtmlEncoder encoder)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.RenderAtEndOfFormTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.<RunAsync>g__Awaited|0_0(Task task, TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext, int i, int count)
AspNetCore.Areas_Customer_Views_Basket_Index.ExecuteAsync() in Index.cshtml
+
{
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
```

Comment: Did you explicitly allowed lazy loading? And if not, did you use "Include" statement in your repository query?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Include`? You can use the Include method to specify related data to be included in query results.

```
var basketLine = db.BasketLines
        .Include(b => b.Product)
        .FirstOrDefault(b => b.BasketId == BasketId && b.ProductId == productId);
```

[[Source]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)